# Synology DS414j: Is Docker and Gitlab supported?

Tags: nas, synology

I've got a Synology DS414j NAS and would like to install Docker and Gitlab but I can't find them in the Package manager. Isn't it supported for my DS414j?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported officially. You could try to install Docker as optware, but you still won't be able to run official Gitlab images, because DS414j uses an ARM CPU and most Docker images (including Gitlab) are built for x86. So all in all, it's not possible without manually building the Gitlab image yourself for unofficial optware Docker which you also have to figure out yourself.

Comment: So what you say is that the package in the link below is for x86?
https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/packages/Docker-GitLab
EDIT: I guess it is. My model is not mentioned in the compatibility list.